# How to get vendors count from dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe

```
area                                                    vendors
electronic city                                         zomato
electronic city                                         zomato
electronic city                                         swiggy
Anekal, Electronic City                                 swiggy
Konappana Agrahara, Doddathoguru, Electronic City       zomato
electronic city                                         swiggy
electronic city                                         swiggy
electronic city                                         swiggy
```

I need count of vendors for perticular area. For example, area=electronic city is having two vendors zomato and swiggy,so I should get vendorslist=1~2 where vendorlist is the variable where we have to store the results.
and also
I need column of vendorNames which will be like this way

```
area                                                    vendorNames
electronic city                                         swiggy,zomato
Anekal, Electronic City                                 swiggy
Konappana Agrahara, Doddathoguru, Electronic City       zomato
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of unique vendors by area you can simply use

```
In [10]: df.groupby(['area'])['vendors'].nunique().rename('vendorlist')                                                                                                                                    
Out[10]: 
area
Anekal, Electronic City                              1
Konappana Agrahara, Doddathoguru, Electronic City    1
electronic city zomato                               2
Name: vendorlist, dtype: int64
```

Is this what you need or what do you mean with `vendorlist` and `1~2`?

Comment: vendorlist will give us count how many vendors are there for perticular area. As in the data I have given area electronic city is having two vendors zomato and swiggy, so result must be 1~2. 1~2 is nothing but the count of number of vendors in perticular area